# "the set of the day" & "that was my line"

Tags: idioms

I fished out two idioms from watching Point Break I haven't met before:

1. "the set of the day" Context: two guys are surfing and one points out a big wave and says 'it is the set of the day' , which I gather should mean 'it's the biggest and meanest'
2. "that was my line" Context: a couple of guys are extreme snowboarding and one of them dies. The guy who chose the slope expresses guilt: 'That was my line!' Another guy calms him down: 'The moment he chose to follow it was his line!'

Could you expand a bit and also give more examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**<thing> of the day** is often used to mark the specified thing as the most significant thing (of that type) that you will encounter on that day.  I assume that "set" is some surfing slang for "a large, surfable wave", so saying that a wave is "the set of the day" means that it is the most impressive, challenging wave that has come along that day (and no other, later waves are likely to equal or surpass it).

You'll likely hear things like "catch of the day" (biggest fish caught) or "play of the day" (most impressive sports action).  Of course, other time frames can be specified too; "Storm of the century" and "man of the hour" are also popular phrases.

**That was my line** is normally used to mean "you just said what I was going to say".
 However, that is not how it is being used here; here, **line** has the meaning "a course, path, or direction taken 
by something in motion".  (see meaning 3c at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line).)  In this exchange, the first individual is indicating that he is to blame for choosing the area, and the path, that led to his partner's death.  (The second person then points out that the dead person chose to snowboard the path too, and it was his own responsibility to navigate it successfully.)

Comment: http://set.urbanup.com/110963

Answer (score 0):

"set" and "line" seem to be slang specifically associated with surfing and snowboarding, respectively. From context we can guess that "set" refers to a wave and that "line" refers to the path taken down a mountain.

Expressions like "of the week", "of the month", "of the year", "of the century" can be used when referring to a record-setting event within that time interval, for example "the biggest", "the strongest", "the most intense", and so forth. For instance, if we call something "[the storm of the century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Storm_of_the_Century)", it means the strongest storm within a 100-year time span.

So in your example, they must have been talking about the biggest wave of the day.